# What is better between tf.data.dataset and tf.train.string_input_producer for large scale dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, dataset

everyone.

Now, I am dealing with a large scale dataset, and I am new for constructing large scale dataset. I read lots of materials, and find that it has two methods:1. tf.train.string_producer 2. tf.data.dataset.

I am not certain about what is better, I think tf.train.string_producer is from the previous version and not optimized well, is it right? or is there a better method to construct a large scale dataset?

Thank you !!

Comment: `tf.data.Dataset()` is the best for large scale datasets.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you! I tried tf.data.Dataset() and feed numpy format into it.